# semi-offtopic question locked

Tags: support

I saw [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43406/pi4j-for-orange-pi-plus-2) semi-offtopic question that is locked, but :

- I can answer it, because it in my experience too to use OrangePi with Raspberry ones
- It is related to RPi too, because sunxi kernels are working well on RPi as far as I tried them
- the question is locked for even commenting

So - I ask for help : how can I help that user?

Comment: If you believe an off-topic question can be re-phrased or edited to make it on-topic, suggest this in a comment or (in some cases) make the edit yourself and leave an explanation in a comment.  Closed off-topic questions which are edited are placed in a "reopen" queue and they are occasionally re-opened -- but beware that this is not automatic and most are *not* re-opened since the usual approach is just to add "I am am using a raspberry pi and...." which does not automatically make it now on-topic.  I.e., editing for re-open usually requires a serious effort and not something flippant ;)

Comment: @Alexey The question has been changed to on hold now, if you'd like to propose an edit.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43406/pi4j-for-orange-pi-plus-2) (though you don't mention which question). While this may be a question you can answer that does not change the fact that it is off topic on this site. I am against reopening this question to allow you to comment/answer because it would set a precedent.

Comment: Steve is absolutely correct and I am baffled that there is any confusion about this at all.  "I can answer the question" very obviously does not make the question on topic here, or else there are (almost) no off-topic questions since someone somewhere can presumably provide some kind of answer to (almost) any question.

Comment: such a problem can be on RPi too if you're using sunxi linux kernel. This kernel will work well on RPi and will cause exactly the same problem

Comment: @Steve Sure, but all you need to do is s/orange/raspberry/g on this question and the question stays the same but it becomes on topic. That doesn't mean the question is on topic as-is, but there is a very clear edit that can make it on topic, and I'm surprised it was locked for editing and commenting (putting the question on hold is the typical approach, locking it is not). There is no reason for it to be locked rather than on hold.

Comment: @JasonC I don't know how it was locked and not merely put on hold, but it is unlocked.

Comment: OK, my edit of this question was rejected, but **not** by the question starter... Requesting for comments...

Comment: OK after some checking the edit was rejected as conflicting with the original author's intent. As your intent was to help the OP you can post a comment or an answer